# Integer to date in Python: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I want to create a new column DATE in the dataframe transaction from the column DAY (lists days from beginning of the study). Like, if DAY is 1, I want DATE to show 2014-1-1, or if DAY is 12 it should be 2014-1-12. This is what I am doing to convert days into date and it works:

```
import datetime
def serial_date_to_string(srl_no):
    new_date = datetime.datetime(2014,1,1,0,0) + datetime.timedelta(srl_no - 1)
    return new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

However, when I try to use this formula to add a new column, it doesn't work:

```
transaction['DATE'] = serial_date_to_string(transaction['DAY'])
```

**TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series**

But the DAY column type is int64. I tried to search on forums and found that the formula could be adjusted, if I try to use this:

```
def serial_date_to_string(srl_no):
    new_date = datetime.datetime(2014,1,1,0,0) + (srl_no - 1).map(datetime.timedelta)
    return new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

It still gives **AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'**.

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map`

```
transaction['DATE'] = transaction['DAY'].map(serial_date_to_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameters `origin` for starting day and `unit=d` for `days`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DAY':[1,12,20]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DAY'] - 1, origin='2014-01-01', unit='d')
print (df)
   DAY       date
0    1 2014-01-01
1   12 2014-01-12
2   20 2014-01-20
```

For same ouput add [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DAY'] - 1, origin='2014-01-01', unit='d').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print (df)
   DAY        date
0    1  2014-01-01
1   12  2014-01-12
2   20  2014-01-20
```

EDIT:

For your function is possible use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
transaction['DATE'] = transaction['DAY'].apply(serial_date_to_string)
```

Performance is similar, `apply` here is fastest for 10k rows:

```
import datetime
def serial_date_to_string(srl_no):
    new_date = datetime.datetime(2014,1,1,0,0) + datetime.timedelta(srl_no - 1)
    return new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    

np.random.seed(2021)
df = pd.DataFrame({'DAY': np.random.randint(10, 1000, size=10000)})
```

---

```
In [17]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df['DAY'] - 1, origin='2014-01-01', unit='d').dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
79.4 ms ± 1.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [18]: %timeit df['DAY'].apply(serial_date_to_string)
57.1 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [19]: %timeit df['DAY'].map(serial_date_to_string)
64.7 ms ± 5.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```